# Chart.js Line chart changes its y axis dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, charts, javascript-objects

[image: I got this chart]

**I am implementing admin dashboard that will show information about CPU usage**

So i need to show range of values on y axis from 0-100 (in percentage), but when i try to implement this, chart dynamically changes y axis values instead of being from 0-100 static

`javascript`

```
new Chart(document.querySelector('#lineChart'), {
          type: 'line',
          data: {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [{
              label: 'Line Chart',
              data: [20, 30, 80, 15, 5, 4, 55],
              fill: true,
              borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
              tension: 0.1
            }]
          },
          options: {
            scales: {
              y: {
                type: 'linear',
                ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true,
                  stepSize: 20, // Customize the step size if needed
                  min: 0,
                  max:100,
                  suggestedMax: Math.max(maxValue,100), // Set the maximum value of the y-axis to 100
                },
              }
            }
          }
        });
```

`html`

```
          <canvas id="lineChart" style="max-height: 400px; display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 234px; width: 469px;" width="469" height="234"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that the option values change, but some of them are misplaced in your configuration object, so they are ignored.

The `min`, [`max`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#common-options-to-all-axes), `beginAtZero` and `suggestedMax` options should be keys of the `scales.y` object, that is, they should be outside the `ticks` object. However, if you set `min: 0` and `max:100`, you don't need the other two.
The only one of your options that is well placed inside the `ticks` object is [`stepSize`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#linear-axis-specific-tick-options).

```js
new Chart(document.querySelector('#lineChart'), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Line Chart',
            data: [20, 30, 80, 15, 5, 4, 55],
            fill: true,
            borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
            tension: 0.1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                type: 'linear',
                min: 0,
                max:100,
                //beginAtZero: true,
                //suggestedMax: Math.max(maxValue,100), 
                ticks: {
                    stepSize: 20, // Customize the step size if needed
                },
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="lineChart" style="max-height: 400px; display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 234px; width: 469px;" width="469" height="234"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-ZwR1/gSZM3ai6vCdI+LVF1zSq/5HznD3ZSTk7kajkaj4D292NLuduDCO1c/NT8Id+jE58KYLKT7hXnbtryGmMg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```